# Non-vanishing of order at prime $p \neq 2$ of sequences of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb N_0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

> Does there exist $(k+1)$-tuple $(a_0,a_1,...,a_k) \in \mathbb {N_0}^{(k+1)}$ and an odd prime $p$ such that $p$ does not divide all numbers in the set $\{a_0,a_1,...a_k\}$ and elements of the set $\{a_1,...a_k\}$ are not all equal to zero but $ ord_p(\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_in^i) \neq 0 $ for every $n \in \mathbb N$?

Under this at first sight maybe complicated question there should be an explanation. Here, $ord_p(w)$ is the function that has value $a$ if $p^a$ divides natural number $w$ but $p^{a+1}$ does not divide $w$. It has value $0$ if and only if $p$ does not divide $w$.

Requirement that elements of the set $\{a_1,...a_k\}$ are not all equal to zero prevents from producing constant polynomial $P(n)=c=a_0$, where $c$ is multiple of $p$. Requirement that $p$ does not divide all numbers in the set $\{a_0,a_1,...a_k\}$ prevents us from obtaining a polynomial which is trivially divisible by $p$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial $n(n+1) \cdot ... \cdot (n+p-1)+p$ does the job for every $p$.

Comment: Perhaps you have a $(k+1)$-tuple in mind, as called for in the problem statement, but it is worth setting out the correspondence more plainly.  In any case your claim of a solution surely deserves a reasoned mathematical argument to support it.